# How to view border/popup for 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, styles, storyboard

I want to animate a border like popup which will be visible for 5 seconds then collapse. When the border is visible, it will be only visible for 5 seconds and then collapse. This will be repeated everytime the border is visible. I have tried but it only appearing once. Can someone please explain to me the mistake in which I have made?

Here is the Style that i have implemented

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="NotificationStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="NotificationStoryBoard">
                            <Storyboard >
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>

                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:05" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

Here is border...

```
<Border Name="NotifciationPopUp" Background="White" Height="80" Width="200" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed"  Margin="10,0,0,10" Style="{StaticResource NotificationStyle}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized hides the border in such a way:

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="NotificationStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" BeginTime="0:0:0" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1.0" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" BeginTime="0:0:5" From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1.0" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
           </Trigger.EnterActions>
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Name="MyBorder" Width="100" Visibility="Hidden" Height="50" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="OrangeRed" Style="{StaticResource NotificationStyle}">
        <TextBlock Text="Some information" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>

    <ToggleButton Name="MyButton" Content="Show border" Width="100" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

In code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    if (MyButton.IsChecked == true) 
    {
        MyBorder.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    if (MyButton.IsChecked == false)
    {
        MyBorder.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    } 
}
```

From his experiments I understood that if the property was once used in animation, then working with it is only possible from the animation-triggers. Accordingly, the access code of the property I have not received.

Besides, then the control's used Visibility=Collapsed, he it does not receive messages from the system and the animation will not work. Although a property "Hidden" should take messages, but I have not worked as well as animation, so in example I used **opacity**.